# in python pandas, how to save a 'grid chart'?

Tags: python, pandas

i am quite new to pandas plot facilities, in the doc, the following command is really handy:

```
myplot = rts.ret.hist(bins=50, by=rts.primary_mic)
```

however, the problems comes when i try to get a figure reference from the plot and save it:

```
myfigure = myplot.get_figure()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'
```

what I understand is, rts.ret.hist(bins=50) returns a plot object, while rts.ret.hist(bins=50 returns an array object.

how should I save my figure in this case?

any clue?

thanks!

Comment: try `myplot[0].get_figure()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To save the figure, you could use `plt.savefig`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df.hist(bins=4, by=df['col1'])
plt.savefig('/tmp/out.png')
```

[image]

Comment: trying to use this with pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix().  It only saves a blank image.

Comment: @Selah: Be sure you call `plt.savefig` *before* calling `plt.show()` -- that might be the cause of the problem, if you are calling `plt.show()`. If that doesn't solve the problem, please open a new question with a short runnable example so we can understand and reproduce the problem.

Comment: No luck.  I think my issue might be that the scatter plot saves as an array, and plot.show() doesn't work on that.  Thanks for the input though.