# save dataframe.hist() to a file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to create a dataframe histogram and save it as a file.

Here is my code:

```
ax=df.hist('ColumnName')
fig=ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('pictureName.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The first line works fine; however, the second line returns an error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'.

Because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836892/in-python-pandas-how-to-save-a-grid-chart) shows the get_figure() being applied to series.hist(), I have also tried using `ax=df['ColumnName'].hist()`, which successfully produced a histogram but led to the same error message when I attempted to implement get_figure().

As recommended in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836892/in-python-pandas-how-to-save-a-grid-chart), normally I would skip the get_figure() and the fig.savefig(), opting instead for plt.savefig, but I am making multiple figures.  In my experience, plt.savefig() is unreliable in saving multiple figures, instead saving one figure multiple times, even when I use fig.close() after each figure creation and save.

I very much want to solve this problem as neatly as possible, so that I can carry the solution smoothly into other applications, rather than having to use a different duct-tape fix every time I have to make a graph.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try the following code?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.hist('ColumnName', ax=ax)
fig.savefig('example.png')
```

Comment: That worked fine, thank you!  Can you explain why, though?  It almost seems superfluous to have to use plt.subplots() every time I want to save a single diagram.  I'm also still curious to know why get_figure() didn't work in my context.

Comment: @user36869 `fig, ax` are created in pair when you call `plt.subplots()`. Alternatively, just based on the specific error you saw, the `ax` object is inside the `numpy.array`, you can use `fig=ax[0][0].get_figure()` to return the `figure` object as well. That two dimension is reserved to `nrows` and `ncols` when you put multiple subfigure in a single big figure.

Comment: If no $DISPLAY is available, you need to prepend `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.use('Agg')` (has to appear before pyplot import and possibly pandas import)